# Linq order by day of a datetime in C#

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, sql-order-by

I have an web application that displays employee birthdays for the current month in a GridView.

The birthdays are stored in a SQL Server 2008 DB, they are stored as a complete datetime, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000.

The query is done in a view. I want to sort them by the date of the Month
Example:

```
John Smith Mar 1
Sally Smith Mar 5
Benny Smith Mar 16
```

The problem is that linq statement sorts them by the The year they were born and then by date. So if Sally was born in 1962 and John and Benny were born in 1988 then the GridView displays as so:

```
Sally Smith Mat 5
John Smith Mar 1
Benny Smith Mar 16
```

After digging around I tried doing it this way which another question on here says will work.

```
List<BirthdayCurrentMonthView> record =
                (from tab in db.BirthdayCurrentMonthViews
                 orderby tab.Birthday ascending
                  select tab).ToList();


                string customFormat = "MMM d";

                var ud = record.Select(d => new
                {
                    d.FirstLast,
                    Formattedate = d.Birthday.ToString(customFormat)
                })
                .Distinct()
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.FormattedDate);
                this.grdBirthdays.DataSource = record;
                this.grdBirthdays.DataBind();
```

The problem is that I keep get the error: "No overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguements"

The examples that I've seen do it this way so I'm at loss for why it won't accept it.

If you could help me that would be great. I want the rows on the GridView by the day only. Thanks.

BirthdayCurrentMonthView:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, ActiveDirectoryName, FirstName, LastName, FirstName + ' ' + LastName   AS FirstLast, Birthday, Anniversary, IsActive
FROM         dbo.Employee
WHERE     (DATEPART(month, Birthday) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE()))

EmployeeID (int, not null)
ActiveDirectoryName (varchar(100), null)
FirstName (varchar(50), not null)
LastName (varchar(100), not null)
FirstLast (varchar(151), not null)
Birthday (datetime, null)
Anniversary (datetime, null)
IsActive (bit, null)
```

Birthday Definition in C#:

```
public Nullable<global::System.DateTime> Birthday
    {
        get
        {
            return _Birthday;
        }
        set
        {
            OnBirthdayChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Birthday");
            _Birthday = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Birthday");
            OnBirthdayChanged();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Solution:

```
List<BirthdayCurrentMonthView> record =
                (from tab in db.BirthdayCurrentMonthViews
                 orderby ((DateTime)tab.Birthday).Day ascending
                  select tab).ToList();
```

**THANKS EVERYONE!!!**

Comment: Sounds like Birthday isn't a datetime. Can you confirm its type

Comment: Is it LINQ to objects or some kind of ORM LINQ?

Comment: As Conrad mentioned could you please show us the schema for BirthdayCurrentMonthView?

Comment: Yes Birthday is a datetime in the DB. 
I think it's an ORM LINQ. It's mapped through an entity data model.

Comment: I've updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `Birthday` is not being recognized as a `DateTime`. What happens if you do this:

```
((DateTime)d.Birthday).ToString(customFormat)
```

This should force the Birthday to be a DateTime. Keep in mind that if this is not a valid DateTime, then it will throw an error.

However, you should run your `OrderBy` statement first, then perform your formatting. Ordering a string will order by ABC, not by date.

Comment: You're answering what he's asking, but not really what he's getting at - this will end up sorting the dates as text, which will only occasionally get the correct order.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it although it doesn't make since that it doesn't recognize it as a datetime.

Comment: @broguyman if you sort the dates as strings (unless sortable, like MM-DD), it will not always put them in the order you're probably expecting.  E.g. Jul 4 will be after Dec 1, since J is after D.

Comment: @broguyman if you hover over the variable name, it should tell you the type it think it is. As Tim S. mentioned, though, you should probably be sorting by the actual datetime so that it sorts properly. If you want it in a custom format, then you can sort it first on the actual datetime, then format it afterwards. I will add this to my answer. And, as always, if this fixed your issue, please do not forget to accept it :)

Comment: @TimS. I have updated the answer to suggest a different order of operations to still allow for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this?

```
List<BirthdayCurrentMonthView> record =
                (from tab in db.BirthdayCurrentMonthViews
                 orderby tab.Birthday.Day ascending
                  select tab).ToList();
```

[DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is what you requested. Obviously I still assume that your data context maps Birthday as `DateTime`

Comment: I think that should be `Month` then `Day`, not just `Day`.  That would put Feb 1 ahead of Jan 2.

Comment: @broguyman You should be more specific.  What wouldn't it accept about it?

Comment: @TimS. judging by the question, looks like that's exactly what he wants. Otherwise I would have proposed DayOfYear

Comment: @broguyman let's try the brute force way ;) Press F12 on Birthday and try to tell us what .NET type it is

Comment: It gave this error Error 14 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Day' and no extension method 'Day' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If I combined this answer and the answer above it works Thanks djechelon

Comment: Use `Birthday.Value.Day`.  Also please look up `Nullable` and get a good understanding of it.  Note that this will error if it is null, if you'd rather skip such values, add `where tab.Birthday.HasValue` (or equivalently, `where tab.Birthday != null`).  Or you could use `GetValueOrDefault` to handle nulls, all depends on what the situation is.

Comment: @djechelon Well, he only includes dates in one month, so it's hard to tell, but I think he'd really want `Month` then `Day`, to have a list of all the birthdays in order.  Note that `DayOfYear` isn't quite right, since Feb 29 during a leap year is the same as Mar 1 during a normal year, but you'd really want to consider Feb 29 before Mar 1 under most circumstances.

Comment: @broguyman I quote Tim S., you should never hard-cast a nullable to its type because you can get lots of headaches when a value is null. I thought that in a DB model containing person, the birthday is always known (so not-nullable) but in your case watch out for null values or you could get a bad production crash like I saw once (and we were forced to "fix the bug" because while specs didn't allow nulls there were some due to DB chaos... and the customer was a laaaaaaaaaaarge bank!!)

Answer (score 0):

Update, could the error be because of Nullable? Nullable doesn't have a ToString(arg) method - get Value first.

If I had a list of `DateTime?`, I'd just stack the orderby's and use HasValue

```
  var bdates = new List<Tuple<string, DateTime?>>();
  bdates.Add(Tuple.Create("Sally", (DateTime?)new DateTime(1962, 1, 1)));
  bdates.Add(Tuple.Create("John", (DateTime?)new DateTime(1988, 2, 1)));
  bdates.Add(Tuple.Create("Benny", (DateTime?)new DateTime(1988, 1, 1)));
  bdates.Add(Tuple.Create("Joe", (DateTime?)new DateTime(1988, 1, 2)));
  bdates.Add(Tuple.Create("Bob", (DateTime?)null));

  var v = bdates
    .Where(bdate => bdate.Item2.HasValue)
    .OrderBy(bdate => bdate.Item2.Value.Day)
    .OrderBy(bdate => bdate.Item2.Value.Month);
```

Comment: What do you expect `OrderBy` on an empty list to do?

Comment: ok so i copy pasted too quickly - that's what i get for trying to stackoverflow fast!

Comment: I think that should be `Month` then `Day`, not just `Month`.  (it wouldn't be `DayOfYear` either because of leap years)

Comment: I agree, better to be complete than assume he'll continue the idea through :)

Comment: That's not right for ordering by two elements.  Should be `.OrderBy(...Month).ThenBy(...Day)`.  Otherwise you first order it by `Day` alone, then ignore that and order it by `Month` alone.